# 2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query - Pymysql Microsoft sql server management Studio

Tags: python, database, database-connection, robotframework, pymysql

import pymysql

import pymysql.cursors

def database_connect():

```
connection = pymysql.connect(host='XXXXXXX',
                             user='XXXXXXXX',
                             password='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
                             db='XXXXXXXX',
                             port=default,
                             charset='utf8mb4',
                             connect_timeout=600,
                             cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT VERSION()")
data = cursor.fetchone()
print ("Database version : %s " % data)
connection.close()
```

Error :" 013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query". 
Any solution, Please.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `pymysql` to connect to MS SQL? Maybe you wanted to use `pymssql`. Better check the correct drivers from https://franz-see.github.io/Robotframework-Database-Library .

Comment: I Used know Pymssql. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

import pymssql

def database_connect():

```
  connection = pymssql.connect(host='XXXXXXX',
                         user='XXXXXXXX',
                         password='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
                         database='XXXXXXXX',
                         port=default,
                         connect_timeout=600)
```

cursor = connection.cursor()

cursor.execute("SELECT VERSION()")

data = cursor.fetchone()

print ("Database version : %s " % data)

connection.close()